# Change bitmap size without create a new bitmap

Tags: winapi, bitmap

I created a bitmap using CreateDIBSection and specified .biWidth = 100 ;  .biHeight = 100 like this pseudo-code :

```
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biWidth = 100;
pBitmapInfo->bmiHeader.biHeight = 100;
....
CreateDIBSection(DibDC, pBitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, 0, 0, 0);
```

Later, i want to reuse this bitmap, just change the bitmap size to 300x100 (and may clear the old image because i don't need it anymore). Many one say I need to create a new bitmap with new size and delete the old bitmap. But I expected in someway that we can re-use the old bitmap. I don't want to re-create a new bitmap because it cause slow performance while i need to do it repeatly many times. So is there any way to change the bitmap size without re-create a new bitmap?

Comment: If you need the bitmap in two sizes, I'd create two bitmaps. Resizing probably looks bad. You don't need to create anything repeatedly, just let each bitmap "live" as long as it is needed.

Comment: Which environment are you using? Surely not all of VB/C/C++/Delphi.... I'd suggest deleting all of those tags and simply adding `WinAPI`.

Comment: Like strings, bitmaps are immutable. Once created, they cannot be modified. What you can do, however, is to display part of a bitmap only, or stretch it using `StretchBlt`.

Comment: @UliGerhardt because the bitmap size will change randomly in both width and height . I can't create thousand bitmap with various size and let they live as long as i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about performance it is indeed not a good idea to keep destroying and creating bitmaps.

There is however an easier solution. Simply create a pool of bitmaps in predefined sizes and use bitmaps from the pool as needed.

If you have a long lived DC, you can use:

```
hBitmap100x100 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(MyDC, 100,100);
hBitmap300x300 = CreateCompatibleBitmap(MyDC, 300,300);
```

If you keep changing DC's then use a DIB section

```
hBitmap100x100 = CreateDIBSection(DibDC, pBitmapInfo100x100, DIB_RGB_COLORS, null, 0, 0);
hBitmap300x300 = CreateDIBSection(DibDC, pBitmapInfo100x100, DIB_RGB_COLORS, null, 0, 0);
```

Just keep reusing these over and over.
You can even have a dozen of them in an array if you like.
You create them at program startup and dispose of them when done.

Comment: `MyDC` is a temporary resource that will change often during execution (and not exist at all sometimes); these bitmaps would have to be DIB sections, not compatible bitmaps.

Comment: thank you so much Johan, I'm very appreciate this alternative method. I've preliminary tested and found this method increase my performance significantly. I'm doing some more testing before mark this answer as the best one.